# Ionic Navigation - Don't update navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hey guys I created a navigation concept in Ionic:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
        <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

<script id="list.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="First page">
        <ion-content class="padding">


            <a  nav-direction="back" nav-transition="android" href="#/movie/1">
                <button class="button button-positive">
                    Tabellen
                </button>
            </a><br/><br/>

            <a nav-direction="forward" nav-transition="android" href="#/movie/1">
                <button class="button button-positive">
                    Live-Ticker
                </button>
            </a><br/><br/>

            <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="changePage()">
            Funktion
            </button>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="view.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Second page">
        <ion-content class="padding">
            <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/h9KwSJVt5n4bEnTXkBJ2?p=preview

The problem is that I want to use my own navbar. With my style, text buttons...
Also I don't want the navbar to update. When I switch the page right now the navbar shows a back button and change title. I want to stay the same...

Answer (score 1):

<strike>http://plnkr.co/edit/OxdP5xj3400fJmAODQxy?p=preview</strike>

Just remove the `ion-nav-back-button`

And set the required title in the `view-title` property of `ion-view`

---

UPDATE -

This is what you want -

http://plnkr.co/edit/dU0u6cwUQxah5E0UCvHX?p=preview

Here, I have removed the `ion-nav-bar` and use a custom bar div.
Plus, you will need to set class `has-header` manually to `ion-content` to have top padding.